# Fail in release output via Proguard (Android)

Tags: android, android-proguard

My application run correctly in dedug mode and no have problen.
But when try to Release app ، meet below Warning :

```
  Warning:android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompatApi22: can't find referenced method 'void setRatingType(int)' in library class android.media.session.MediaSession
  Warning:android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatApi22: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo getTraversalBefore()' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
  Warning:android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatApi22: can't find referenced method 'void setTraversalBefore(android.view.View)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
  Warning:android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatApi22: can't find referenced method 'void setTraversalBefore(android.view.View,int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
  Warning:android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatApi22: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo getTraversalAfter()' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
  Warning:android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatApi22: can't find referenced method 'void setTraversalAfter(android.view.View)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
  Warning:android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatApi22: can't find referenced method 'void setTraversalAfter(android.view.View,int)' in library class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo
  Warning:there were 7 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
:app:proguardRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**In searches i found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159728/android-studio-cannot-resolve-getdefaultproguardfile) and [this one](http://www.metaandroid.com/question/android-studio-cannot-resolve-getdefaultproguardfile/).**

so , `I changed the compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion from 21 to 22` but not work!

other gradle details :

```
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
```

---

```
buildTypes {

    debug {

        buildConfigField "String", "key", "\"value\""
    }
    release {

        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard_file.txt')

        buildConfigField "String", "key", "\"value\""

    }

}
```

it's my mistake or happened other events!?

Comment: Try `getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')` instead of `proguard_file.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in your proguard file -dontwarn android.support.v4.**